# Obtaining object from function by reference instead by value

Tags: c++, function, stack, shared-ptr

I wonder if code below is correct - it works in this case but it may be just because of its simplicity. What makes me wonder: function (f1) returns object by value but in function which called it (f2) I obtain this object by reference not by value. Is this a problem? I wonder because it looks a bit weird to me but it works and i think it should works. Because object is created on the stack of f1 and then returned (by value) to stack f2 and after that a reference is obtained to this object on f2 stack which was created on f1 stack. What do you think about this?

```
class A {
public:
    A(){a=100; b=200;}
    int a;
    int b;
};
typedef boost::shared_ptr<A> AP;

AP get(){
    AP a = AP(new A());
    return a;
}


AP get2(){
    AP const& a = get();
    return a;
}

int main() {
    AP const& a = get2();
    std::cerr << a->a << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's weird, but safe.

Binding a temporary object to a reference extends its lifetime to that of the reference; so what you're doing is equivalent to creating a local object variable. The use of a reference adds obfuscation, requiring the reader to know these odd rules to understand what's happening, but doesn't change the program's validity or behaviour.

Comment: BTW, when was that changed (this used to be undefined behaviour in pre-ANSI C++)?

Comment: @Axel: I don't know, I've only used C++ since 1998 or so and haven't studied prehistoric dialects. It was certainly the case in C++98.

Comment: Thank you for this answer but i have another one. This way is weird yes but isn't it faster than obtaining by value because of that I create only reference instead of calling operator= ?

Comment: @MichalW: No, in both cases an object is created - a temporary if the variable is a reference, and the variable itself if it's an object. Using a reference *might* be slower, since (in principle) it needs to be dereferenced to access the object, but a decent compiler should be able to undo your attempt to confuse it and generate the same code that it would when accessing the object directly.

Answer (score 1):

In the both cases

```
AP const& a = get();
```

and

```
AP const& a = get2();
```

You bind a temporary object with a const reference. The object will be alive while there will be alive the reference. So there is no problem with your code.

Comment: Ok, good :) And BTW. I understand that const have nothing to do with lifetime of this temp object right?

Comment: @Michal W You may bind temporary objects with const references. If you will remove the qualifier const from references then you will get a compilation error.